# How to get all lines from one file which contain a string in another file?

Tags: python, linux, bash, file

File 1:

```
a
a
b
c
d
```

File 2:

```
a a1
b b1
e e1
f f1
```

My desired output:

```
a a1
a a1
b b1
```

I am trying to implement this using bash or Python.

In python I tried:

```
f1=open("file1")
f2=open("file2")
dpo1=f1.readlines()
dpo2=f2.readlines()

for i in dpo2:
    for j in dpo1:
        if j in i:
            print i
```

In bash I was thinking of using grep but grep will give the output that matches the entire line but this is not the case here. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the search function ?

Comment: Have you tried egrep? You can do something like `egrep '^a'` to match all lines starting with the letter `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works finally.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$0 in a{print $0,a[$0]}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk

Will work if the string matches any field.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(a[$i]){print;next}}' file{1,2}

a a1
b b1
```

For edit

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(a[$i]){for(j=1;j<=a[$i];j++)print;next}}' file{1,2}

a a1
a a1
b b1
```

Comment: what changes should I make for repetitions? Check my recent edit.

Comment: This is working fine but this is sorting the output in ascending order. I want to keep the order as in file1. What changes should I make?

Comment: @kaushaya, what do you mean, it works through the lines in the second file, there is no way for it to be out of order

Comment: Yeah the second file is sorted in ascending order but the first file isn't. Any way I can get the output in the order of the first file? As contrary to the example given above, the first file is a subset of the second file. That means, all the strings are definitely contained in the second file.

Comment: Post your real data because i have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If files are not large, just do

```
dpo1 = [i.strip() for i in dpo1]
lines = [i.strip() for i in dpo2 if(any([j for j in dpo1 if j in i]))]
>>>lines
['a a1', 'b b1']
>>>for i in lines:
...    print i

'a a1'
'b b1'
```

Comment: It does not give any output for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
f1=open("file1")
f2=open("file2")
dpo1=f1.readlines()
dpo2=f2.readlines()
for x in dpo2:
    for y in dpo1:
        if y.strip() in x:
            print x.strip()
            break
```

For each line in dpo2(source file, which generate the outputs), test if it contains one of line in dpo1(conditional file). If we get a match, print it and break for next line in dpo2.

Comment: code only answer is not a good answer. Please explain what you're doing.

Comment: OkOk. For each line in dpo2(source file, which generate the outputs), test if it contains one of line in dpo1(conditional file). If we get a match, print it and break for next line in dpo2.

Comment: Thats O(M*N). Bad solution. Can be done in O(M+N) with space either O(M) or O(N) which ever is smallest.

Comment: It does not give any output.